# Starting Docker containers with combined list for volumes with ansible

Tags: docker, ansible

I've a problem by starting a docker container with volumes from a combined list with ansible.

One list is defined at defaults, so each container need that:

```
  standardvolumes:
    - '/usr/share/zoneinfo:/usr/share/zoneinfo'
```

The other list can be defined in group_vars.yml for host group but doesn't needs to be. Here an example, where it is defined:

```
  volumes:
    - '/usr/data:/data'
    - '/usr/data2:/data2'
    - '/etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/pem:/etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/pem'
```

Now I combine "standardvolumes" and "volumes" to use one list for docker deployment:

```
  - name: Combine volume lists
    set_fact:
      volumestostart: "{{ standardvolumes|default([]) + volumes|default([]) }}"
```

As "volumes" isn't necessary to be defined I'm using the default([]) stuff.

This is my docker deploy task:

```
  - name: Startup a new startable Container
    docker_container:
      name: '{{ service }}'
      image: '{{ pathtoimage }}:{{ release }}'
      published_ports: '{{ publishlines }}'
      volumes:
        - '{{ volumestostart }}'
      env:
        TZ: "{{ timezone }}"
      env_file: '/etc/sysconfig/{{ service }}.list'
      etc_hosts: '{{ hostsentries }}'
```

Now when I deploy a container, where "standardvolumes" and "volumes" is defined, everything is fine. But when I deploy a container where "volumes" is not defined I get this error:

```
failed: [shs_de_postd_server1] (item={u'key': u'qit', u'value': {u'cgrouptype': u'blech', u'nexususer': u'cbs-qit-user', u'notstartable': u'no', u'nexuspassword': u'48vhw63u', u'nexusport': u'8191', u'nexuspath': u'ftg/postd-server', u'graylogip': u'tcp://10.20.30.40:12201'}}) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "item": {"key": "qit", "value": {"cgrouptype": "blech", "graylogip": "tcp://10.20.30.40:12201", "nexuspassword": "48vhw63u", "nexuspath": "ftg/postd-server", "nexusport": "8191", "nexususer": "cbs-qit-user", "notstartable": "no"}}, "msg": "Error creating container: 400 Client Error: Bad Request (\"create ['/usr/share/zoneinfo: \"['/usr/share/zoneinfo\" includes invalid characters for a local volume name, only \"[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]\" are allowed. If you intended to pass a host directory, use absolute path\")"}
```

Where is the difference? I didn't get it. The standard volume is the same in both parts.

Comment: Are you sure that in this case you don't have **both** `standardvolumes` and `volumes` being an empty array?

Comment: jep, standardvolumes is defined in defaults.yml in my role.
But I found the error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the error, this works fine:

```
  - name: Startup a new startable Container
    docker_container:
      name: '{{ service }}'
      image: '{{ pathtoimage }}:{{ release }}'
      published_ports: '{{ publishlines }}'
      volumes: '{{ volumestostart }}'
      env:
        TZ: "{{ timezone }}"
      env_file: '/etc/sysconfig/{{ service }}.list'
      etc_hosts: '{{ hostsentries }}'
```